# SpringMVC - Maintaining static lists like countries etc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

This must be very basic question, but wanted to confirm the best practice used.
1) Say my countries & states reside in database - i need to populate them into a drop-down list on the html form.
Because the list like countries/states do not change often, i want to pull them from database only once and maintain this array in some singleton class.

Please advise what is the best way to do this..

2) can i also maintain these lists in the xml/ properties file - and load them in to static variables.

Comment: What is the reason to store them in a database if you consider the list as completely static? I would simply load the list every time you need it. This should be fast enough, extremely simple, and will work fine even when you realize the list is not as static as you initially thought. If it really causes a performance problem (which I doubt), then using a cache abstraction can solve it without modifying the code.

Comment: Hi, this list may not be as static as it sounds to be(countries). There can be minor changes and having them in database helps centralized data for all the applications.

Comment: Then you should not do as if it was static, and you should not cache it forever in a singleton. I stand by my previous comment.

Comment: So loading the list from database and holding it in a session bean? Is that how your insist ?

Comment: I'd not hold it anywhere. Just load it every time you need it. As you would do with any other non-static list.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using [`java.util.Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/locale/create.html) with enumeration constant. Since this country list hardly changes and if you don't have other related information to save with country then it's better not to save country in database.

Answer (score 0):

I would pull them from the DB as referenceData only on the form that actually needs them.  You could cache them in the middle tier, only loading them the first time - but it's likely not worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

In case if you use JPA you could consider to enforce the [use of second-level cache](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkjio.html).